Which direction is the rolling shutter on a Canon 5D?
(I worked something out from first principles, and it surprised me, so I am hoping for some confirmation I got the details right, or a correction if I got them wrong.)
This high speed video of Canon 5D Mk II's shutter action shows that when taking still photos, the first curtain opens up by sliding down from the top of the camera, following shortly afterwards by the second curtain. For short shutter speeds, it forms a slit that exposes from the top of the sensor to the bottom.
Because lenses invert the image onto the sensor, this means the bottom of the image is the first part to be exposed.
However, this video of a rolling shutter test on a Canon 5D Mk IV (associated article DP Review article) shows that, when taking video, buildings and poles are distorted to appear to lean toward the direction of the pan. If the camera pans left, the top of the building appears further to the left than the bottom. That is, the top of the image is being read first, and the bottom last.
My conclusion is that the electronic rolling shutter is in the opposite direction to the physical shutter in a Canon 5D.
I am assuming there was no changes in the direction of the physical or rolling shutter behaviour between Mk II and Mk IV.
That seems plausible, but somehow surprising to me. Did I reach the right conclusion?

Related only: When taking photos from cars at speed at 90 degrees to direction of travel (eg out a passenger window) in landscape mode  a rolling shutter causes vertical objects such as fence posts or railing bare to lean progressively if the shutter slit moves vertically. Hold the camera upside down and the lean is in the opposite direction. ||BUT If you shoot in portrait mode you get X axis compression or expansion deep-ending which side of the camera is held upwards. These 4 options MAY allow somewhat more desirable photos to be taken in some cases. Or not :-) .

Related: If a rolling shutter travels from top to bottom, why does this image seem to show skew in the other direction?. Every Canon camera I've used (including the 5D Mark II, III, and IV as well as the 7D and 7D Mark II) are all the same in terms of sensor readout direction. Which shutter curtain closes to end exposure in Electronic First Curtain mode does vary from one Canon model to the next.

@MichaelC: that is a direct duplicate that I failed to find. Good spot. Voted to close my question.

Your conclusion of the readout direction in the video is correct.
I believe all Canon cameras with electronic shutter readout from top to bottom of the image.
